# How to get Bitmap width/height createjs

Tags: bitmap, size, easeljs, createjs

I am using createjs 0.8.0 and having a problem getting Bitmap size.
It always return 0

Here's my snippet:

```
    var imgVisa     = new createjs.Bitmap("assets/images/Visa_logo.png");
    console.log("imgVisa x : " + imgVisa.image.width);
    var imgVisaX    = initialXpos;
    var imgVisaY    = canvas.height - 300;
```

it will have **imgVisa.image.width = 0**.

and if I am using :

```
imgSplash.Bitmap.width
```

It will throw me error : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined*

Anyone can help ?

Comment: I noted this on the (deprecated, we drive people here now) CreateJS community. In addition to the solution below, there is no `Bitmap` property of Bitmap instances. instead use `imgSplash.image`.

Comment: yes, I am aware it now...
I am using preloadJS now so I can do everything I want after preloading my assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to preload the image first:

```
    var img = new Image()
    img.onload = function() {
        // gets called when the img is loaded
    };
    img.src = 'img.png';
```

Keep in mind, that the onload function is called when the image is loaded, so it's async.

Comment: is there no way to do it before onload?
I need to set the position of the image depends on its size

Comment: Nope, the image has to be loaded first - otherwise you can't check the size... You could use something like PreloadJS and preload all of your images first and then build your Canvas once everything is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bitmap.getBounds().width

Comment: This will only work once the Bitmap's image is loaded.